# In Xcode 5, how can I build with iOS SDK 7.0 even though I have iOS SDK 6.1 in SDKs directory?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I have upgraded Xcode 4.6.x to 5 today. Before I did, I backed iPhoneOS SDK 6.1 in Xcode 4.6.x up for placing it to 'SDKs' directory of Xcode 5 after upgrading. I really need to keep an old version of SDK for my app to build with 6.1 SDK. Because I didn't fix it compatible with iOS 7 environment yet.

I upgraded it and copy the old SDK to 'SDKs' directory of Xcode 5. then I was able to see 'iOS 6.1' option at [Build Settings - Base SDK]. I also expect that my app can be built with one of SDKs with an option I choose.

When I chose 6.1 SDK, It works well. But, 7.0 SDK didn't.
I choose 7.0 SDK to use brand new features of iOS 7, but Xcode 5 actually uses 6.1 SDK.

Why does Xcode 5 always select 6.1 SDK rather than 7.0 SDK?

Comment: Installing older versions of the SDK is not supported. There's a good chance it will not behave correctly. I strongly recommend not doing this. If you need iOS 6.1, then keep Xcode 4.6 installed (you can have multiple Xcode installs at once).

Comment: @KevinBallard yes. thank you for good advice. I'm not sure if it is safe or not. I'll get careful consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do three things.

1. Clean your project.
2. Reset the simulator.
3. Quit the simulator.

Now run your project in Xcode 5.

Comment: Thank you. It works well. does the simulator's setting have an effect on iOS device?